# Rails 4 - Chained Scopes Work in the Console But Not on View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several scoped methods.  When I call them in the console, I get the expected results.  When I view them, the scopes are not applied.  I see "all", regardless of the filtered scope method.  Any ideas?

**EDIT** - I'm using Ransack to filter results, hence the `@search`.

Also, do you guys know a cleaner way to compare a datetime to 1.year.ago?  What I have below works in the console, but I'm sure there's a nicer way to compare.

Thanks in advance.

**invoice.rb**

```
  def self.open
    where(closed: false)
  end

  def self.this_year
    current_year = 1.year.ago
    where("invoice_date >= ?", current_year)
  end
```

**invoices_controller:**

```
  def index
    @search = Invoice.this_year.open.search(params[:q])
    @invoices = @search.result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
    @count = @invoices.count
    render 'shared/invoices.html.erb'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where `search` is coming from, but perhaps it removes existing scopes?

The easiest way to determine the issue is probably to dive into the controller method with [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry).  In your Gemfile:

```
gem "pry"
```

Then run `bundle install`.

And in the controller

```
def index
  binding.pry
  # ...
end
```

Try to reload the invoices page, and you will see that the request hangs.  Head over to your server logs, and you should see a console-like prompt.

This will allow you to run `Invoice.this_year.open.to_sql` and then `Invoice.this_year.open.search(params[:q]).to_sql` to review how scoping changes.

Also, I'm not sure it gets much cleaner than `where("invoice_date >= ?", 1.year.ago)`.  Seems pretty declarative to me.  What don't you like about the expression?

Comment: binding.pry was very painful to install on my computers (actually its dependent gems), and I think it is overkilled to install a gem in this situation. As you suggest in the second part of your answer `Invoice.this_year.open.search(params[:q]).to_sql` should be sufficient to debug this case

Comment: Hmm, sorry to hear you had installation troubles.  It drops in without issue for me.  I agree with you generally, but I'd reach for pry in this situation because the code looks reasonable, and I have a feeling `search` is doing something unexpected. In other words, some extended debugging might be in order.

Comment: I'm using Ransack, hence the `@search` - I tried loading without the @search like this: `@invoices = Invoice.this_year.sorted.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)` but get the same result

Comment: Following this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805426/how-can-i-use-scopes-with-ransack-in-rails-3 It seems that your code should work @KatieM (I googled "Ransack scope")

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that another scope method was causing the issue:

```
scope :sorted, order("invoice_date DESC")
```

I removed that scope option from the Ransack call and it worked.

Thanks all.